# Java image button

Tags: java, image, button

I'm trying to add a button in the middle of the page, over an image. I tried several methods, and I ended up with this one. I'm not sure why but it sure doesn't act like a button (the animations when pressed/released).
Here is a piece of code

```
public class Window extends JFrame
{
    public static final int WIDTH=400, HEIGHT=550;
    private JPanel panel=new JPanel();

    public Window()
    {
        super("Tetris");
        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel.setBackground(new Color(176,224,230));

        add(panel);

    }

    public void addLogo()
    {
        String address="C:/Users/Lorena/Desktop/Calculatoare Engleza/Anul II/OOP/Tetris v2//bin/Tetris/tetris.png";
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(address);

        Image img = icon.getImage();
        Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(320, 150,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
        icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);  

        JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
        label.setIcon(icon); 
        panel.add(label);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel); 
    }

    public void addStartButton()
    {

        String address="C:/Users/Lorena/Desktop/Calculatoare Engleza/Anul II/OOP/Tetris v2//bin/Tetris/play.png";
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(address);

        //Used to  resize image
        Image img = icon.getImage();
        Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(200, 200,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
        icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);  

        /*JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(icon); 
        panel.add(label);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);*/

        //this.add(panel2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton start=new JButton(icon);
        start.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        start.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        panel.add(start);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel); 

    }

    public void addBottomFirstPage()
    {
        String address="C:/Users/Lorena/Desktop/Calculatoare Engleza/Anul II/OOP/Tetris v2//bin/Tetris/bigbricks.png";
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(address);

        Image img = icon.getImage();
        Image newimg = img.getScaledInstance(370, 150,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
        icon = new ImageIcon(newimg);  

        JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
        label.setIcon(icon); 
        panel.add(label);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you comment out the line

```
// start.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

it should appear as a normal button.

Otherwise, I don't know what you expect it to do since the border is typically responsible for the 'click' animation.

Comment: That's the fact, I didn't know what it would  exactly do. Thanks